# Hide the third div content using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a HTML like this:

```
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 1 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 2 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 3 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 4 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 5 </div>
```

What I want to do is to apply CSS to third div only using CSS by accessing their class names. I want the content 3 with the red colors.
This HTML is out side of body tag and generated through JS.

What can I try next?

Comment: `outside of body tag` what do you mean?

Comment: this is just an example. i am using image Cropper,. which generates some HTML divs out side of body tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**:
As requested, for this particular case, jQuery can also be used, so the following code will work

`$('.imgareaselect-handle').hide().eq(2).show()`

.

***Remaining answer***:

Check this CSS pseudo-selector [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), click run button to verify

```css
.imgareaselect-handle:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 1 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 2 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 3 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 4 </div>
<div class="imgareaselect-handle"> Content 5 </div>
```

> The :nth-of-type(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element. See :nth-child for a more thorough description of the syntax of its argument. This is a more flexible and useful pseudo selector if you want to ensure you're selecting the same type of tag no matter where it is inside the parent element, or what other different tags appear before it.

Comment: can you post the exact location of this html in source code?

Comment: http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

if you try cropping image here on this link , there are small square you will see on the corner of the cropper,. what i want to do it i want to hide all those small selector squares except the right bottom corner.

Comment: can you use jquery for this? css is working but i have seen the html, it's much complex for css to handle

Comment: yeah , i would like to use it if possible,.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the jquery, check it now